# how to upgrade Hazelcast for java app in k8s from 4.x to 5.3.6?

Tags: hazelcast, java-17, spring-boot-3

how can an existing java app currently deployed/running in kubernetes be upgraded from 4.x to 5.3.6?

after changing the dependency to hazelcast-spring v5.3.6, the sync (redeployment) failed indicating that the “enterprise” version of Hazelcast (and proper licensing) is required for a “rolling upgrade”

is there a way to upgrade to hazelcast-spring v5.3.6 w/o need of the enterprise license “rolling” upgrade capability?

why isn’t simply changing the pom.xml Hazelcast dependency version adequate?
(there are no compile has no errors)

thx
Hazelcast newby

Answer (score 0):

The Rolling upgrade Enterprise feature is for zero-downtime scenarios.

If you can shutdown your Hazelcast cluster (i.e. all Hazelcast members), and start the cluster newly using the new version, then it's completely fine with the Community (opensource) version too.

Comment: to clarify - should simply deleting the app deployment (kills pods, etc) accomplish what you’re suggesting? after doing so, I’m seeing a “Kubernets API access forbidden”, “configure RBAC”, etc

Comment: It depends on how your configuration looks like. Do you use embedded Hazelcast (i.e. members running in the same JVM as your app) or client-server mode (i.e. only client instance is created in the same JVM)? The recommended way is to use client-server mode. You can deploy Hazelcast in K8s manually or use the Hazelcast Platform Operator. There is also a helm chart.

Comment: thx - I'm only sure that the app runs fine at the old v4.0.6 (hazelcast-all).    it's been difficult to see what exactly has changed in v5.3.6 that would now fail the k8s deployment.   there are no compile issues - imports from v4.0.6 are still supported (so apparent code changes were needed)...  which is why - particularly as a newby - I am stumped as to why the k8s (jenkins) deployment now fails